# Adding relevant links to existing posts

Tags: discussion, editing

What do you guys think about adding relevant hyperlinks to questions and answers?

For example, if someone asks about hygiene in certain country, an answer could include quality of water, restaurant cleanliness and such. Adding info on water quality from UN site or a blog post about someones experience in a restaurant regarding hygiene is what I had in mind for hyperlinking. Adding links to outside websites (official government or organization data, blogs, articles) would in my opinion be useful as it would allow readers to learn a bit more than what the answer is providing.

I will add that kind of link to my posts but was wondering whether others would mind if someone else edited their posts for the sole purpose of adding a relevant/interesting link.

Comment: Related: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/617/is-it-okay-to-add-an-image-to-somebody-elses-question

Answer (score 7):

If you're editing in order to provide sources for facts already stated in the answer, do it. That's one of the reasons we allow editing: to improve answers and make them more complete.

If you're editing to provide *new* information, you might be better off just creating a separate answer.

Just a reminder to everyone reading this: you have no reason to expect that your posts will remain exactly as you wrote them, in perpetuity. When you post anything on Stack Exchange, you agree to our [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal), which explicitly state that everything posted here is licensed by Creative Commons (which says that other people can modify your work), and [our FAQ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#editing) also lets you know that other people can edit your stuff:

> All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons and this site is
>   collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that
>   needs improvement, click edit and help us make it so!
>
> All edits are tracked in a public revision history. To view revisions,
>   click the edit date on the post.
>
> If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being
>   collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the
>   site for you.

If someone edits incorrect information into a post, or deviates from the original intent of the person who posted the question or answer, the post owner can roll back the revision and the community can adjust their votes (each time the post is edited, you are allowed to change any vote you may have cast).

If you want to add a comment asking if the OP minds you adding in information, that's fine for the sake of politeness, but it is not at all required.

Comment: Thanks for an official answer Laura!

Comment: I would prefer an official answer to this question: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/998/travel-se-design-support-request ...

Comment: @roflcoptrexception Jin has been on leave a bunch lately, but I hadn't realized this site's design hadn't gone up. I'll look into it after the holiday.

Comment: You guys get an end-of-November holiday? (-;

Answer (score 4):

If you find information that can supplement a question/answer, it's common courtesy to ask the OP in a comment to include it in their post. It's okay to edit, format, and rearrange a post, and I have done so on many occasions, but I would think twice before including new information (which includes links) without the poster's consent. Occasional link to Wikipedia or similar is probably fine though.

If the OP doesn't respond to your request at all (inactive user, for example), then I guess it's okay to include new and relevant information, seeing as probably nobody would mind.

Comment: Asking the OP first is very sensible!

Answer (score 2):

I would not do it. This is about reciprocity. I would not appreciate either if someone in my own posts. Correcting a typo is fine, but anything further is out of scope. For me it's a matter of respect.

Rather than fiddling about others' answers I would rather suggest an alternative answer of my own, with links or whatever I think is missing. Then the readers can decide via the voting mechanism.

Comment: Good to know. Was actually more interested in what others think than actually doing it.

Comment: The folks who own and run Stack Exchange specifically go out of their way to tell us that OP's do not own their posts and that everybody is encouraged to edit and improve them. To this end all posts are wikis and the goal is to end up with a great set of questions and answers. It is true that this sometimes can lead to some posts drifting away from what they said when people voted on them. To address this we have the ability to change our vote after a post has been edited.